# What is the Status of Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1

Tags: azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework

I am looking for a sync framework to use for syncing sql server express and sqlite databases with Sql Azure. We have been using Sync Framework 2.1 for a while with sql server express and Sql Azure with good success, but Sync Framework 2.1 is getting quite old. Does anyone know if Sync Framework is dead? If so, does anyone know of a good alternative.

Comment: Are you writing mobile apps?  If so, consider Azure Mobile Services (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/Mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/). (Disclosure: I work on this product)

Answer (score 0):

the last update was the Sync Framework Toolkit (supposedly v4.0) that was released a couple of years ago...

afaik, no update (a 2.2 release was on put hold) and it's still supported (there's has been no official announcement that it will be discontinued)

Comment: If anyone stumbles on this, it became unsupported in Jan '21 (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-sync-framework-21)